# Port unreachable; telnet says connection refused

Tags: centos

All, i am trying to do telnet on a port say 443, however i am getting connection refused error. The source and destination ip's are in the same network segment, so there is no question of blocking the ports on the network layer. Source is a linux server running on centos 7. We have multiple linux machines in the same network segment, all are able to reach that port except one linux machine. I disabled the firewalld and selinux in the source linux machine and i don't see any reason for the telnet to fail here. Any thoughts on how do i troubleshoot further.

Comment: From the server, share the output of #lsof -Pi:443

Comment: On the affected machine, a typo in the target address or port? Strange subnet mask or unintentionally different network configuration? What happens if you disable the firewall not just on the client but also (temporarily, of course) on the server?

Comment: @roaima No anomalies on the subnet mask or network configuration . Destination Ip is a LB serving 3 real servers in the backend. But it should not allow all, if there is any issue in the LB. Highly suspecting on the client side.

Comment: LB has different networks front and back?

Comment: On target, run up `wireshark` or its command-line counterpart `tshark`. Can you see the SYN packets arriving from the client? And the SYN/ACK or RST packets being sent back?